# Ability to search completed DocuSign envelopes based on who completed the document

Tags: docusignapi

We were looking at ways to search completed envelopes based on who completed the document. The thought was to rename a completed envelope based off a Custom Field or even the Full Name field. We started looking at utilizing the API but ran into these questions:

1. Can the API be used to rename a completed envelope using values from specific document fields?
2. Can the API write form field data into custom envelope fields so then we can use the native search option to search by custom envelope fields?
3. Has anybody created a custom search page to search via the API. The goal would be to search by name and/or form fields of completed envelopes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot rename a completed envelope. Completed envelope cannot be modified in any way.
2. Yes, you can use custom fields this way. See [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-custom-tab-values/)
3. You can search by name/email and other fields. See [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatus/) for details.